# Mockk clear mocks between test execution

Tags: java, kotlin, testing, mocking, mockk

I don't understand exactly why those tests are working correctly (it's not real code but it's the same as my class):

```
class AClassTest {
    private val dep: Dep = mockk()

    private val testedClass = TestedClass(dep)

    @Test
    fun testMethod1() {
        testedClass.method1();
        verify(exactly = 1) { dep.method() }
    }

    @Test
    fun testMethod2() {
        testedClass.method2();
        verify(exactly = 1) { dep.method() }
    }
}
```

Why do tests pass without resetting mocks? Is Mockk resetting mocks automatically?
I expected a `@BeforeEach` or an `@AfterEach` method calling `clearMocks` to clear mock state.

Maybe clearing is necessary only to clear behaviours, not inspected data?
So in this case, why those tests are working correctly?

```
class AClassTest {
    private val dep: Dep = mockk()

    private val testedClass = TestedClass(dep)

    @Test
    fun testMethodOnIllegalArgumentException() {
        every { dep.method() } throws IllegalArgumentException()
        assertThrows<IllegalArgumentException> { testedClass.method() }
    }

    @Test
    fun testMethodOnIndexOutOfBoundsException() {
        every { dep.method() } throws IndexOutOfBoundsException()
        assertThrows<IndexOutOfBoundsException> { testedClass.method() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about kotlin testing frameworks, but for example JUnit creates new instances of `AClassTest` for each test case (and therefore implicitly new instances of the mocks)

Comment: Well kotlin tests are executed with junit so probably the motivation is the same. But so I still don't understand why at the kotlin conf they say that recreate mocks every test is expensive... Look at this video: https://youtu.be/RX_g65J14H0?t=1145
If the class is freshly instantiated for each test case, how call clearMocks in a @Before method should be faster?